# django-allauth verification email send with example.com:port

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am working with django-allauth. I manage to do everything, however the port is rendered within confirmation email:
so it looks like that:
http://example.com:8000/accounts/confirm-email/NA:1kcaUA:3NeRmjX502XujDEy_PmwHsV_rW3ioNjOvWcclXFBD5

is there any way to get rid of the port while sending those ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You need to edit your project's sites. Log in to django admin, then navigate to the field 'sites' and edit your site domain name and display name. Currently it is likely set to example.com, which is why django-allauth picks up this site name in its [template](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/templates/account/email/email_confirmation_message.txt).

Comment: Thank you! I'm embarrased to say that I had misconfiured [dpaste.com](https://dpaste.com) in exacly this way in a recent database migration, and a number of new users got "Activate your account on example.com" notifications. Nobody complained, but it's fixed now!